# Click event on div in JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets, uirepeat

I have a list represented by a ui:repeat, where each item is a div with some data. What I want is to show the item detail by clicking on the div.

I made it with a button refreshing the form but can't make it work with onclick event on panelGroup.

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="container" layout="block">
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.model}" var="item">

            <h:panelGroup styleClass="item_data" layout="block">
                ID: #{item.id}
                <h:commandButton action="#{bean.select}" value="Select item">
                    <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}"/>
                    <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup styleClass="detail"
                layout="block" 
                rendered="#{item eq bean.selected}">
                value: #{bean.selected.value}
            </h:panelGroup>

        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to show the detail section without re-rendering the whole form? If so, then wrap it in a component which is always rendered in the HTML DOM tree, give it an `id` and refer it instead:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="item_data" layout="block">
        ID: #{item.id}
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.select}" value="Select item">
            <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}"/>
            <f:ajax render="detail" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="detail">
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="detail"
            layout="block" 
            rendered="#{item eq bean.selected}">
            value: #{bean.selected.value}
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax rendering of content which is by itself conditionally rendered](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichIsByItselfConditionallyRendered)

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you actually want to invoke JSF ajax action by `<h:panelGroup onclick>` no, that's not possible as it doesn't support `onclick` attribute. You could use a `<div>` with [`jsf.ajax.request()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.request) function, but cleaner would be to use a `<h:commandLink>` with CSS `display: block` so that it spans the entire div.

```
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="item_data" layout="block">
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean.select}" value="ID: #{item.id}" styleclass="detailLink">
            <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}"/>
            <f:ajax render="detail" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

with e.g.

```css
.detailLink {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: My question was about how to make the same functionality without the commandButton, just with the 'click' event on the panelGroup 'item_data'. The behaviour that I pretend to simulate is div onclick event. By the way, thanks for the correction.